# Populate hidden text input using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input name="input1" id="input1" type="text" value="" class="problem">

<input name="input2" id="input2" type="text" value="" class="hidden">
```

I'm trying to populate a hidden text input (e.g. `input#input2`) field with the current value from another text input field (e.g. input#input1) (un-submitted) using jQuery. I've sourced this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/S9mUL/5/) doing exactly what i require but with a drop down field. And i was wondering if anyone is able to point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Sorry if i wasn't clear, the jsfiddle works perfectly but i'm trying to use a text field instead of a drop down to populate the other field.

Comment: looks like it is working correctly in the jsfiddle you provided

Comment: Are you sure you have any problem??

Comment: The problem is i'm trying to alter the jsfiddle to use a text box to populate the other field, rather than a drop down.

Comment: So put the same handler on  your `input` instead of on the `select`. If you don't know how, then you really need to start with a beginner's tutorial\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i always handle this by storing that value in a variable:

```
var yourText = document.getElementById("input1").value;
```

and then just plug it into the hidden field:

```
$('#input2').val(yourtext);
```

here's your hidden field:

```
<input id="input2" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge. Will this work even if the input value is unsubmitted? I can't seem to get this to work in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Don't worry, i've fixed this! http://jsfiddle.net/S9mUL/1247/ Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#my_form").submit(function(event){

var visibleInputVal = $("#input1").val();

if(visibleInputVal != ""){
    $("#input2").val(visibleInputVal);
}else{
    alert("you need to provide a value for input 1");
    event.preventDefault();
}

});



<form id="my_form">
<input type="text" value="" id="input1" />
<input type="hidden" value="" id="input2" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```